# a query to count all records of the same tablename but different schemas

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need a query or a script that will do the generate the following:

```
select count(*) from events_abc;
select count(*) from events_def;
select count(*) from events_123;
```

Ideally i would like to do a sum of all the counts,but if I can't then a list of all the counts would be a nice start.

I need to do this for Amazon Redshift. The catch is I have many different schemas which can have the same table name.

So schema `john__foo` can have a table name `events_abc` and schema `mary__foo` can also have a table named `events_abc`.

Would I use some kind of cursor? What would be the best way to script this?

Comment: Are you looking for a raw SQL query or a script?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - it doesn't have to be a SQL script. I have a lot of tables to query. So whatever I can do to make it work. I'm fine with a bash script too if that's possible. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From  [Amazon RedShift Dev Guides - Examples of Catalog Queries](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_join_PG_examples.html)

> ### List the Schemas and Tables in a Database
>
> The following query joins STV_TBL_PERM to some PG tables to return a
>   list of tables in the TICKIT database and their schema names (NSPNAME
>   column). The query also returns the total number of rows in each
>   table. (This query is helpful when multiple schemas in your system
>   have the same table names.)
>
> ```
> select datname, nspname, relname, sum(rows) as rows
> from pg_class, pg_namespace, pg_database, stv_tbl_perm
> where pg_namespace.oid = relnamespace
> and pg_class.oid = stv_tbl_perm.id
> and pg_database.oid = stv_tbl_perm.db_id
> and datname ='tickit'
> group by datname, nspname, relname
> order by datname, nspname, relname;
>
> datname | nspname | relname  |  rows
> --------+---------+----------+--------
> tickit  | public  | category |     11
> tickit  | public  | date     |    365
> tickit  | public  | event    |   8798
> tickit  | public  | listing  | 192497
> tickit  | public  | sales    | 172456
> tickit  | public  | users    |  49990
> tickit  | public  | venue    |    202
> (7 rows)
> ```

This is more or less what you are looking to do, isn't it ?

So just play around with this query. If you are already connected to the right database, and want to list all the tables begining with `event_` in all schemas, you should do this :

```
SELECT datname, nspname, relname, SUM(rows) AS rows
FROM pg_class, pg_namespace, pg_database, stv_tbl_perm
WHERE pg_namespace.oid = relnamespace
  AND pg_class.oid = stv_tbl_perm.id
  AND pg_database.oid = stv_tbl_perm.db_id
  AND relname LIKE 'event_%'
GROUP BY datname, nspname, relname
ORDER BY datname, nspname, relname;
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas G! That helps a lot. Its exactly what I was trying to do. Its a good start. I just need to figure out how to pass in a list of different databases, but for the most part I'm getting the row counts I need. Thanks again!